# Simplifying a multivariate random variable

Tags: probability-theory

$(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4)$ is $Multi(n,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4)-distributed.
 $

I want to simplify the expression for the vector $(X_1,X_2)$, where $X_1=Y_1+Y_2$ and $X_2=Y_3+Y_4$.

Is the simplification related to the pmf of $X_1$ and $X_2$ or?

Comment: $X_1$ will have binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\theta_1+\theta_2$ and $X_2=n-X_1$, i.e. the number of failures if $X_1$ denotes the number of successes.

Comment: What confuses me is what the simplification of the components of $(X_1,X_2)$ has to do with their pmfs? Is a stochastic variable equal to its pmf/pdf, or why do we simplify it in this way?

Comment: PMF or PDF are determining for the *distribution* of a stochastic variable.

Comment: Yes, but why do we simplify the vector in terms of its distribution? The components of the vector doesn't represent a distribution?

Comment: By the way when you say that $X_1$ will have parameter $n$, this parameter is not related to the original $n$ from the multivariate random variable?

Comment: Yes it is the same $n$. Further I don't understand what you are really after. Simplification of the expression $(X_1,X_2)$? It is a vector with (only) 2 components... How to make that more simple? A simplification of PMF is possible: $P(X_1=k,X_2=n-k)=\binom{n}{k}(\theta_1+\theta_2)^k(\theta_3+\theta_4)^{n-k}$.

Comment: Ok, maybe im making it more complicated than it is. But I thought that each component should be simplified so that the whole expression gets simplified. Maybe the pmf is a simplification then..

Comment: Is the distribution of the vector $(X_1,X_2)$ binomial or multinomial? I get that each component is binomial distributed, but what about the vector?

Comment: "Multi" is "more than one" and "bi" is "two" so formally binomial is a special case of multinomial. You are dealing with that case here and can call the vector binomial. It is common to use the term "binomial" also when it concerns a single random variable. Especially the successes by a fixed number $n$ of experiments. Of course then there are failures too, but their number is determined by $n$ and the number of successes, and is not very interesting to go for a vector $(X,n-X)$. If you think that $(X_1,n-X_1)$ is more simple than $(X_1,X_2)$ then you can recognize it as a "simplification".